# Uncaught Error: Unexpected value 'SharedModule' imported by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation

Tags: angular, angular-cli, nativescript, symlink, angular2-nativescript

I'm working on an Angular 4 project that sible three platform (mobile with NativeScript, web and desktop with Electron). since I will have several codes to share between these three projects (services, models, pipe ...) I have created a shared folder in each `src` folder of each of these 3 applications. I made a copy paste to synchronize this directory at the level of these 3 platforms.

Very quickly the project began to grow and synchronization became a headache, so I start doing some research. I had several proposals but the one that seemed to me the simplest and which already parted with what I was doing was to put the shared folder in the root directory of the solution and with a symlinks I synchronize the contents of the folder in each project.

So I used a pretty nice code found on GitHub to create symlinks
https://github.com/NathanWalker/angular-seed-advanced/blob/master/tools/install.js

but when I generate the project I have this error that I can not understand

```
compiler.es5.js:1690 Uncaught Error: Unexpected value 'SharedModule' imported by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.
at syntaxError (compiler.es5.js:1690)
at compiler.es5.js:15382
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at CompileMetadataResolver.webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js.CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (compiler.es5.js:15365)
at JitCompiler.webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js.JitCompiler._loadModules (compiler.es5.js:26795)
at JitCompiler.webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js.JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (compiler.es5.js:26768)
at JitCompiler.webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js.JitCompiler.compileModuleAsync (compiler.es5.js:26697)
at PlatformRef_.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.PlatformRef_._bootstrapModuleWithZone (core.es5.js:4536)
at PlatformRef_.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.PlatformRef_.bootstrapModule (core.es5.js:4522)
at Object.../../../../../src/main.ts (main.ts:11)
```

but what's shady is that when I delete the symlinks and I put my file back manually all build normally.

1. Is the symlinks the cause of this error? (I have the impression). If so, how to solve it?
2. Is there another simple and effective way to share my angular code between several projects?

Comment: thanks @hafler for the corrections. i speak french so ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find a solution after some searching on Google.

It seem to be a problem in angular-cli webpack. Refer to this link for more details : https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/3148

To solve the problem you should put your symlink source on another drive of your computer. It works fine for me.

1. I put my shared module folder on Disk drive C:\
2. I create a junction symlink from the shared folder to the 3 projects destinations folders (on Drive D:). and all files are sync. It's beautiful.

Comment: Hi @halfer i spkeak french. my english is not good ;) thanks for the correction

Comment: Merci @halfer. bonne journée